# Why does wait expression cause blocking

Tags: system-verilog

I have the following code in one of my monitor:

```
   virtual task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
      forever begin
     mon_trx = tx_upconv_in_transaction::type_id::create("mon_trx");
     wait (vif.chind2 == 32'h0);
     mon_trx.xi = vif.xi;   
     mon_trx.xq = vif.xq;
         $display("TRX.XI = %h, TRX.XQ = %h", mon_trx.xi, mon_trx.xq);   
      end
   endtask: run_phase
```

When I run the simulation I can see many prints (of the display), but the time doesn't pass.

Why?

p.s
chind 2 is integer (data).

Comment: @toolic - like what?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably because `vif.chind2 == 1'b0`? If the expression being waited for is already true when the `wait` statement is executed, then the `wait` statement will not block.

If you want to wait for `vif.chind2` to become `1'b0`, how about replacing your `wait` statement with:

```
wait (vif.chind2 != 32'h0);
wait (vif.chind2 == 32'h0);
```

Comment: Yes. For the `vif.chind` change to 1'bo.

Comment: @noobuntu- chind 2 is integer (data), so I'm not sure that I can refer to negedge/posedge in its case.

Answer (score 0):

`wait` statement is level-triggered, not edge-triggered. If your signal is always 1'b0, then it will execute without blocking.

If you are looking for a negedge, you can change it to

```
wait ($fell(vif.chind2));
```

This detects a negedge on your signal and blocks until then.